# Upload an image(MultipartFormData) request objctiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a post request.
Here is my try:

```
-(void)Test{

NSDictionary * orderMasterDict = @{@"distributorId":@10000,
                                   @"fieldUsersId": @3,
                                   @"itemId":@0,@"orderMatserId":@56358                                                 };

Globals.OrderDetailsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:orderDetailsDictAnatomy,orderDetailsDictTexture,orderDetailsDictTranslucency, nil];

NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:Globals.OrderDetailsArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSData *postData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:orderMasterDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

NSString *jsonString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[_params setObject:jsonString2 forKey:@"orderMaster"];
[_params setObject:jsonString forKey:@"orderDetails"];
[_params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"3"] forKey:@"userId"];
[_params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ALRAISLABS"] forKey:@"subsCode"];

// the boundary string : a random string, that will not repeat in post data, to separate post data fields.
NSString *BoundaryConstant = @"----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";

// string constant for the post parameter 'file'. My server uses this name: `file`. Your's may differ
NSString* FileParamConstant = @"imageUpload";

// the server url to which the image (or the media) is uploaded. Use your server url here
NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.102:8080/Demo/Test/create"];

// create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in _params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// add image data
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_uploadImageView.image, 0.6);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// set URL
[request setURL:requestURL];


NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if (error){
        NSLog(@"ERROR :",error);
    }else{
        NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
        NSLog(@"response status code: %ld", (long)[httpResponse statusCode]);
        if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {
            NSLog(@"StatusCode : %ld",(long)[httpResponse statusCode]);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }
    }
}] resume];}
```

How to make a multipartFormData request?
 I tried googling for it, couldn't find any answer suitable for this situation, and thought well .Please help me finding the right solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you change your image in `NSData` then help of `AFNetworking` you can post your image.

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
imageData = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions: NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

Then use this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *finaldictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[finaldictionary setObject:imageData forKey:@"image"];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager POST: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", IQAPIClientBaseURL, kIQAPIImageUpload] parameters: finaldictionary constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) { }
    progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success response=%@", responseObject);
        NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseObject options: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error: nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", responseDict);
    }
    failure: ^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"Errorrrrrrr=%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . please take a look at  the updated question . This is what i am trying to do. please help me getting the right result.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

By using Alamofire

```
-(void)CreateOrder{
NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR URL"

NSDictionary * orderMasterDict = @{@"distributorId":stakeholderID,
                                   @"fieldUsersId": userID,
                                   @"itemId":@0,@"orderMatserId":@0                                                 };

Globals.OrderDetailsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:orderDetailsDictAnatomy,orderDetailsDictTexture,orderDetailsDictTranslucency, nil];

NSDictionary * consumerDetails = @{@"consumerName":Globals.PatientName,@"consumerReferenceId":Globals.PatientID,@"notes":Globals.PatientNotes,@"cunsumerContacNumber":@"456464654654"};


NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:Globals.OrderDetailsArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSData *postData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:orderMasterDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

NSString *jsonString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 //retrieving userId from UserDefaults
prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString * userIdString = [prefs stringForKey:@"userID"];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"orderMaster": jsonString2, @"orderDetails" : jsonString ,@"userId" : userIdString,@"subsCode" : @"ABC_MDENT"};


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlString parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    //For adding Multiple images From selected Images array
    int i = 0;
    for(UIImage *eachImage in selectedImages)
    {

        UIImage *image = [self scaleImage:eachImage toSize:CGSizeMake(480.0,480.0)];

        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.3);
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"imageUpload" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file%d.jpg",i ] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
            i++;
    }
} error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager
              uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
              progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                  });
              }
              completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                  NSLog(@"responseObject : %@",responseObject);

                  if (error) {
                     NSlog(@"error")
                  } else {
                      NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

                      if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {
                          resposeStatusCode = [responseObject objectForKey:@"statusCode"];
                      }else{
                          NSLog(@"requestError");
                      }
                  }
              }];
[uploadTask resume]; }
```